# AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches name"

Tags: react-native

AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'

C:\Users\WindsorInfosys.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\a454618c5126fef26c4dc0b0485e08b2\res\values-v26\values-v26.xml:13:5-16:13: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.

I have got this errors when i added react-native-voice to my project and trying to generate the apk.

```
buildscript {
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.2"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 27
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
}
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try changing your dependencies of react native voice to this

```
implementation(project(':react-native-voice')) {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
        exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
 }
```

then add below code to your app/build.gradle

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 28
                buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```